# Login to Hotmail using WebBowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

i'm trying to login to Hotmail using the WebBrowser control. the problem is as i get the document completed event, and call:

```
HtmlElement elementsByTagName = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signInTD");
```

or

```
HtmlElementCollection elementsByTagName = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

i get nulls. i've tried using HtmlAgillity Pack, and still i get the same result.
i know it used to work in the past as i`ve seen samples doing the same thing with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<HtmlElement> inputs = webBrowser1.Document.All
        .OfType<HtmlElement>()
        .Where(el => String.Equals(el.TagName, "input", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```